# how to write total method in JFrame and i am using netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

![***The three text boxes in this program initially disabled. To enter value in the each text box you would check mark the each check box for an item a customer was purchasing. 
This would enable that item's text field so you can enter the quantity. You would do this for each type of item the customer was purchasing.When you entered the quantities of each item, you would click the Total button. This would show output in the text area similar to that in the image below:

You can enter a discount in the Discount field if you wish. If a discount was entered, it would also appear in the output:

The Reset button puts the form back to its original state (quantity text fields disabled and cleared, check boxes unchecked, text area and discount field cleared).
The Exit button prompts you - are you sure you want to exit? If the user confirms that they wish to exit, the program terminates.

***][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1B0T.jpg)

Comment: how to do this? short answer **by writing code!**

Answer (score 2):

You need to learn Java Swing. You can learn it here.

[JFrame Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html)

EDIT:

A good thing along with learning how to use JFrames is learning how to use many of Swing components

You need to learn more/less of the following Components:

JPanel - [JPanel tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html)

Layout Managers - [Layout Managers Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

JLabel - [JLabel Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)

JTextField - [JTextField tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html)

JButton, JCheckBox - [JButton, JCheckBox, Etc tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

JTextArea - [JTextArea tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html)